# Error while calling asmx webservice Missing DLL Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data 3.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, asmx

I am getting below error while calling web service (ASMX) hosted on IIS

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

I have checked that Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data and all dependent files in bin folder that all are with version 5.0.414.0

Also, I have checked on GAC whether this file is present or not but there are no such files.

**I would like to know where this version 3.0.0.0 is coming from.** Where this version is defined?

I have searched word 3.0.0.0 in whole IIS directory there is no such word.

I have checked using SOAP SONAR tool to call web service.

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at ProcessData(String Number)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</faultstring>
      <detail/>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

All other environments its working properly but we are facing this issue on one client only. due to DLL missing error its not going into code also that is i have checked

Comment: Is this specific client calling an operation that other clients are not? It seems unlikely to me that it could fail for just one client.

Comment: Yes, the calling method is same for all. but I would like to know where this 3.0.0.0 version its fetching and checking for that version dll?